# How get parent model from Ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I`m use ember-data 12
I have 2 models, which sideloads together:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: App.Adapter.create()
});

App.Propose = DS.Model.extend({
    meeting: DS.belongsTo('App.Meeting'),   
    time: DS.attr('string'), 
});


App.Meeting = DS.Model.extend({

    name: DS.attr('string'),
    proposes: DS.hasMany('App.Propose'),


});
```

How me get meeting from propose model, for example from some calculated field:

```
App.Propose = DS.Model.extend({
        meeting: DS.belongsTo('App.Meeting'),   
        time: DS.attr('string'), 
        someCalc:function(){
           this.get('meeting').get('name') //I want that. but its not worked
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please make a jsfiddle showing the issue ?

Comment: very outdated usage of ember-data

Answer (score 0):

The way you would do this is:

```
App.Propose = DS.Model.extend({
     meeting: DS.belongsTo('App.Meeting'),   
     time: DS.attr('string'), 
     someCalc:function(){
        return this.get('meeting.name'); // or do whatever operation you need in here
     }.property('meeting.name')
 });
```

But Ember Data has evolved a lot and this will not work (like this) in Beta 2 and later.